# Almost every graph is asymmetric?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Here is a question:

If i choose at random an isomorphism class of graph(no loops, undirected) on n vertices(with uniform probability on the set of such isomorphism classes), is the probability that the resulting graph has trivial automorphism group, going to 1 as n goes to $+\infty$?

I guess yes, but i do not have a neat argument.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Edit 1: I have the same question restricted to the isomorphism classes of regular n graph(each vertex the same degree). Do the asymmetric one appear almost surely also in this restricted space of graphs?

Edit 2: in the comment it turns out that is a theorem of Erdős, the first question. I'm still interested in knowing if my question in Edit 1 has been already answered.

Comment: [This article](http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1963-04.pdf) is one of the references in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph). Interesting topic. I don't know anything about it, though.

Comment: Does the article answer also to the question in the edit? By the way thanks for the reference

Comment: I don't know. It does talk about the first part. And the Wikipedia page talks about the infinite case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k$-regular graphs the answer is also yes, see the paper  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bsudakov/automorphism.pdf by Kim, Sudakov and Vu
for the proof. Note we must exclude $k=0,1,2$ along with complementary cases.

Comment: Beautiful.Thank you very much!